# Creating a logical variable out of a factor variable in R

Tags: r, logical-operators, r-factor

I need to create a logical variable (True-False) out of a categorical (factor) variable

I decided to use the:

```
 dat$var[dat$var %in% c("option1")] <- TRUE
 dat$var[dat$var %in% c("option2")] <- FALSE
```

But I get the following error message in both lines and my entire variable is NA:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, dat$var %in% c("option1"),  :
   invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?
The factor level is right, I copy pasted to make sure there will not be any typos.
I thought of changing the variable to vector `as.logical()` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error is due to `dat$var` being a factor. You can only assign values of pre-specified levels to a factor variable. But you can create the new variable with the following command (assuming `option1` and `option2` are the only values):

```
dat$var <- dat$var == "option1"
```